# Where are the temples for Lord Ganesha along with his wives?

Tags: temple, ganesha

In this post,  [Who were the wives of Lord Ganesha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6546/who-were-the-wives-of-lord-ganesha), I know that Lord Ganesha is married. Are there any specific temple for Lord Ganesha along with his wives?

Comment: The wives of Lord Ganesha are Siddhi and Buddhi. Sometimes referred to as Riddhi and Siddhi. Regarding temple famous for Lord Ganesha along with his wives, one is Siddhi-Vinayak temple in Mumbai, India. Another one is 'Shri Shri Vidya Dham' in Indore, India which I just found recently shows more wives and sons and grandsons of Lord Ganesha. I have discussed regarding this temple in my question [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8671/1018).

Comment: @Aby, I have utilized your comment (with attribution) in my answer below. Do let me know if you'd like it to be removed from my answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Ganesha along with Siddhi and Buddhi is not a rare occurrence. There is also [a beautiful painting of the trio by Raja Ravi Verma](https://www.mojarto.com/artworks/raja-ravi-varma/riddhi-siddhi-ganpati-216096). A few temples dedicated to Ganesha along with his wives, they are:

### [Siddhivinayak Temple](http://www.siddhivinayak.org/), Prabhadevi, Mumbai

From a [comment](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7134/where-is-the-temple-for-lord-ganesha-along-with-his-wives#comment19625_7134) on the question by [Aby](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/1018/aby):

> Regarding temple famous for Lord Ganesha along with his wives, one is Siddhi-Vinayak temple in Mumbai, India.

Undoubtedly, the [Siddhivinayak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siddhivinayak_Temple,_Mumbai) temple at Prabhadevi, Mumbai is one of the most famous temples in India where Siddhi and Buddhi are present along with Ganesha. It was constructed in 1801 using funds from Deubai Patil.

[image: Photo of Siddhivinayak temple]

<sub>Photo from http://siddhivinayaktemple.co.in/photo-gallery/siddhivinayak-temple,-mumbai</sub>.

---

### [Mayureshwara temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganesha_Temple,_Morgaon), Moregaon

This is the most important of the lot. It was here where Ganesha married Siddhi and Buddhi, after slaying the demon Sindhu. Here Ganesha is seated on a peacock, hence the name "Mayur"eshwara. You can get to know the history of this temple [in this other question which I asked.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16521/4459)

[image: Photo of Mayureshwara]

<sub>Photo from http://www.templeadvisor.com/temples-in-india/hindu-temples/mayureshwar-temple</sub>

---

### [Arulmigu Siddhi Buddhi Vinayagar Temple](http://www.royapettahsidhibudhivinayagar.tnhrce.in/), Royahpettah, Chennai

Another very old temple with ages of history. It is one of the [108 Ganapathi Sthalams.](http://www.thehindu.com/features/friday-review/history-and-culture/brahmotsavam-at-melattur/article5071710.ece)  The official website mentions the history of the entire temple.

[image: Photo of Arulmigu Siddhi Buddhi Vinayagar Temple]

---

### [Trinetra Ganesh Temple](http://www.trinetraganesharanthambhore.com/), Fort, Ranthambore

This temple was constructed in 1299, by  King Hameer, a devotee of Ganesha (after the war with Allauddin Khilji concluded). Here, Ganesha is potrayed with three eyes, along with Siddhi and Buddhi. The story of the temple [as mentioned in this blog](https://www.ranthamborenationalpark.com/blog/trinetra-ganesha-temple/) is:

> According to the history behind this temple, it is said that in 1299 AD, a war took place between King Hammeer and Alauddin Khilji at the Ranthambore fortification. During the war time, they filled there godowns with foods and other necessary things in Ranthambhore Fort, where the King dwells. As the war lasted for many years, the stored things in godowns were getting over. King Hammer was a great devotee to God Ganesh. One night when he was sleeping, Lord Ganesh came in his dream and said that all the lacking and problems would be over by tomorrow morning. Next day morning, an idol of Lord Ganesh with three eyes (Trinetra) stamped from one of the walls of the fort. Also, a miracle took place and the war got over while the godowns got filled again. In 1300 AD, King Hammer built a temple of Lord Ganesh. He placed the idol of Lord Ganesh, Riddhi Siddhi (his wife) and two sons (Shub Labh) along with the idol of mushak (mouse, his vehicle)

The temple was shortly destroyed. You can read about that in [Chapter 3 of this book.](https://books.google.com/books?id=LSRJDwAAQBAJ)

[image: Photo of Trinetra Ganesh Temple]