# Do we have any information about other wives (except Riddhi, Siddhi) and grandsons of Lord Ganesha mentioned in any texts

Tags: ganesha

I recently came across a WhatsApp message which showed that there is a temple in Indore, India called Shri Shri Vidya Dham which is the only temple that has idols of full family of Lord Ganesha. Full family here means:

- Lord Ganesha
- His 5 wives, ie, Riddhi, Siddhi, Tushti, Pushti and Shri
- 2 sons, ie, Shubh and Laabh
- 2 grandsons, ie, Aamod and Pramod

Here is a picture of the temple:

[image]

I have already heard and read about Lord Ganesha's wife Riddhi and Siddhi and His sons Shubh and Laabh, but I have not heard of Tushti, Pushti, Aamod and Pramod. I wanted to ask whether we have any scriptural reference for them and any stories about them like who were these ladies and how did they got married to Lord Ganesha. Also did they along with Aamod and Pramod have any roles/responsibilities.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, Tushti, Pushti, and Shri are amsas of Mahalakshmi, who reside in Vaikuntha, and not Ganesha's wives. This is because when Krsna gives his darshan to Akrura in Srimad Bhagavatam, he is being served by his energies, which include, Sri, Tushti, Pushti, Kanti, Gir, Kirti, Ila and Urja. http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/39/53-55
So I don't suppose they can be Ganesha's wives.

Amoda and Pramoda are among the Senanayakas of Mahaganesha who assisted him in the battle against Vishanga, when Devi Lalitambika was engaged in killing Bhandasura's forces, according to Lalitopakhyana.
Senanayakas refer to six commander in chief's of Ganesha's army, who are the partial avataras of Ganesha. So I don't think that they can be his grandchildren.

Comment: @@Surya - Which scripture say that the wives of Ganesha are amsas of Lakshmi in Vaikuntha. Then what about Shakti Ganapathy? Shakti should be amsa of Parvati, dont you think so. Shakti is accepted as wife of Ganesha as per Narada purana. Morover, in South Kartikeya is considered married and Ganesha is not. Now, which story is true. So, please stop indulging in incest by saying that Ganesha's wives are amsas of Lakshmi.

Comment: @Krishna I think you misunderstood - I meant that the only Tushti Pushti and Shri I know are Mahalakshmi, not Ganesha's wives. I'll edit the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: @@Surya - Thanks for the correction and apologies. Because, Goddess Lakshmi, Goddeses Parvati are Maha Maha pativratas. If at all there are some references like that it has to interpreted properly and not blindly say foolish things like lakshmi Ganapathi, shakti Ganapathi etc. Else it would be nothing but incest and sin only. Unfortunately, there lot wrong false gods being propagated like lakshmi Ganapathi, Shakti Ganapathi etc, even temples are constructed by unscrupulous elements.

Comment: @Krishna i think for Lakshmi Ganapathi, there is a legend. After fixing elephant head, Lakshmi asks Parvathi to give her son for some days as Lakshmi didn't have sons. Lakshmi raised him for some days. This is the reason why Ganesha didn't participate in fight of Skanda and Tarakasura. Skanda Purana explicitly says that Ganesha was given to Devas for some days but not sure about Lakshmi story. I will check for this story of Lakshmi and Ganesha in Puranas and inform you.

Comment: @The Destroyer - Whether Lakshmi raised Ganapathi for some or not is not the question here. Some dubious people are ascribing lakshmi as wife of Ganapathi, which is absolute sin. Lakshmi is like mother to Ganesha and depicting Lakshmi Ganapathi as Lakshmi sitting on his left lap is unpardonable.A also,  Shakti Ganapathi appears in Narada purana and there are temples which have cropped up in AP where Ganesha has Shakti sitting on his left lap. So, that Shakti is Parvati, does this kind of depiction mislead people. These kind depictions are absolute incest and sin.

Comment: @The Destroyer - You may say north Indians worship Lakshmi and Ganapathi during deepavali. Yes they worship Lakshmi and Ganapathi as separate deities unlike the one being described as Lakshmi Ganapathi or Shakti Ganapathi, with  goddesses sitting on his left lap.  Infact, Lakshmi and Parvati should not be worshipped without their consorts Vishnu and Siva.

Comment: @Krishna I think Shakti here refers wife (wives) of Ganapathi. If not, then it is really a grave sin. Ganesha is son to both of them. I agree with you.

Comment: @The Destroyer - I agree with you. But imagine, if some body says, parvati-parameshwara or Lakshmi Narayana or Sita Rama, common man simply assumes that they are consorts. By saying Lakshmi Ganapathi or Shakti Ganapathi, what will a guillble common person think. He will be mis lead. also, the section of the deity is that the Goddess is on the left lap of Ganapathi. So, she cannot be his mother whether it is lakshmi or Shakti doesn't matter.  People may argue that this lakshmi or Shakti is not that lakshmi or Shakti, but it does mis lead and it is wrong to depict that way.

Answer (score 4):

In the Devi Bhagvata Purana,the goddess Pushti is mentioned:

> “Pustî” (nourishment) is the wife of Ganapatî. All in this world worship this Pustî Devî. Without this “Pusti”, women or men alike all become weaker and weaker.

Tushti is also mentioned but she is described as the wife of Anata Deva.

Comment: Tushti is mentioned as the wife of Anata Devi? Is there something you're missing or Is it me?

Comment: @Sinister nope it's in the devi bhagavatha purana

Comment: Is Ananta devi male or female?

Comment: @Sinister he is male

Answer (score 2):

Lord Ganesha
His 2 wives,  Riddhi, & Siddhi, 
2 sons, Shubh & Laabh
1 Daughter Santoshi 
Tushti ( Shubh's Wife )
Pushti ( Labh's Wife )
2 grandsons, Aamod and Pramod

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE. You should cite sources to back your answer.