# If Lord Ganesha is married then why is he worshipped as a bachelor.....?

Tags: gods, ganesha

- In India lord Ganesh is worshipped as a bachelor in south india and in north india he worshipped with [wives](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8671/do-we-have-any-information-about-other-wives-except-riddhi-siddhi-and-grandso).

**QUESTION:**

- If lord ganesh is married then why he is worshipped as a bachelor ?
- What is the reason for different way of worshipping  ?

Comment: Of course he is married. You can find the story of marriage of Ganesh ji in Shiva Purana

Comment: @sv. i already attached the link that you given but it is about lord ganesh OTHER wives i am asking did he got married if yes then why some places he is worshipped as a bachelor

Comment: @sv. please read the question completely and mention if it is a duplicate or not

Comment: Your question title is little confusing. You can change to: "If Lord Ganesha is married then why is he worshipped as a bachelor?"

Comment: @sv. correct i'll change it

Answer (score 1):

this is because of different traditions of north and south india. 
on the contrary Skanda is considered as a Brahmachari in many northern places. But in reality both [Ganesha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consorts_of_Ganesha) and [Skanda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devasena) are married. These are regional/cultural differences.

Comment: thanks for answering it but dont refer to wikipedia it is not accurate and refer to more OFFICIAL SITES and  we all are aware of different traditions but we are not worshipping lord hanuman as brahmachari but only lord ganesh and lord muruga(skanda) so WHAT CAUSED THE DIVERSION ?

Comment: there are regional traditions in different places .. in north india Hanuman is brahmachari . In andhra there is a temple of Lord Hanuman with his wife Suvarchala. Same way in South india marrying to uncle's daughter is a common practice but not done in north india.